# I can't get access back to my SSH server

Tags: ssh, centos, putty

Short story, I changed my `sshd_config` file to only key authentication but I didn't create a key for root (I have created however a key for user1 but it doesn't connect too). Is there anything I can do to restore my server?

Also, In my Okeanos account, I can't access my vm's/ server's console, so I can't change it from there.

Please tell me there is a solution!

Edit: I haven't clarified that I didn't add any private keys to Putty. I just added some public keys to the authorized_keys file (those keys were generated with the ssh-keygen command).

[image: error message]

Comment: Looks like putty doesn't have a key configured. In putty > Connection > SSH > Auth, browse to the private key for user1, and try connecting as user1. If you used a okeanos linux image, it should have x2go installed: https://okeanos.grnet.gr/support/user-guide/cyclades-how-do-i-connect-to-a-vm/#suggested-method-x2go . Otherwise, you may need to contact okeanos as to why the console connection doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Please make that an answer.

Comment: ["Solved" does not belong to the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/355310). [Accept your answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) if you want. Questions with accepted answers are considered solved without a need for any garbage in titles.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the comment, I thought I could add it to the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, today I tried again to connect to Okeanos console and I **did** it! I guess it was a temporary problem.